# Do Daken's (Wolverine's son) Muramasa claws wound him when they come out?

Tags: marvel

As stated in this link http://marvel.wikia.com/Daken_%28Akihiro%29_%28Earth-616%29

Daken infused some of Muramasa's blade in its own Claw, as I have also read in http://marvel.wikia.com that Wolverine's claw comes out as a bone, damaging the arms and bleeding out, since he can heal, it doesn't show much.

Now Daken, son of wolverine possesses the same ability with the claw, but has 2 instead of 3 as i saw in the picture.

As I have read some of the weakness of Wolverine is the Muramasa blade, cutting him once and the wound healed for 2 days instead in an instant.

So if Daken did the above, would that wound in his arm heal properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the same link you provide in your question, [Marvel Wikia - Daken (Akihiro) (Earth-616)](http://marvel.wikia.com/Daken_%28Akihiro%29_%28Earth-616%29), there's additional detail under his powers/abilities that describes his retractable claws. One note about his claws is partially pertinent to your question:

> Note: Originally possessed three claws on each arm, one claw each from the underside was laced with the alloy of the Muramasa Blade, which was excised from him. leaving him with two claws on each arm, but as of recently shown he might have regrown his missing claws.

He started with 3 claws, but one was modified to apply the Muramasa blade. He no longer appears to have the 3rd claw after an encounter with Wolverine.

That said, while he did have the 3rd (underside) claw, there was consideration given to the question you pose about healing. From [The Full Wiki - Daken (Earth-616)](http://misc.thefullwiki.org/Daken_%28Earth-616%29):

> The Tinkerer, who bonded the broken piece to Daken's claws, has also implanted artificial housings that act as sheathes inside Daken's wrists that are made of Adamantium. According to the Tinkerer, the substance the Muramasa blade is composed of would severely damage Daken's soft body tissues, hence the presence of the Adamantium sheathes.

Unfortunately, neither of these particular sources are cited, however I believe [this scene](http://www.marvelcomics.pl/wysiwyg/news/2009-05/FirstLooks/27-05-2009/t7.jpg), which appears to come from [Wolverine Origins #36](http://marvel.com/comic_books/issue/24157/wolverine_origins_2006_36), is the one described above between the Tinkerer and Daken.

Answer (score 0):

The Miramusa blade can only harm Wolverine as part of Wolverine's soul is infused in the blade (which is why it hurts him), so Daken's claws being infused with it should not harm him the same way as Wolverine and he should be able to heal just as fast